# What gear for creating a headphone mix for a band

Tags: mixing

I have this mixer `yamaha MG16XU 16-channel` and I'm trying to figure out whether I can create a separate mix for each member of the band with this headphone distributor `Behringer MicroAMP HA400`, or maybe I need a different approach.

The goal is to use headphones instead of speakers.

Thanks,

[Mixer](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/MG16XU--yamaha-mg16xu-16-channel-mixer-with-usb-and-fx)

[headphone distributor](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/HA400--behringer-microamp-ha400-4-ch-headphone-amplifier)

Comment: Doesn't belong in my answer & not an actual recommendation, as I've never used it, but I found some info from PreSonus that covers the topic [not cheaply] - https://www.presonus.com/learn/technical-articles/Selecting-a-Monitor-Mixing-System

Comment: How many band members? What about drums? Is it just vocal mix you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - no, not with one of each of those devices.

The mixer has 4 aux sends*, routable to individual outputs... if you use no effects. Every effect send you need will lose one headphone mix.

[image] [image]

So, with no effects, you could set up 4 individual headphone mixes.

Each of those mixes would need to go to its own headphone amp. The Behringer only has one input to those 4 outputs, so it cannot do individual mixes to each player.

[image]

So, at minimum, for a 4-piece band, you need 4 Behringers.
If you also want FX sends, you need a board with more sends.

*I'm ignoring that some are pre, others are post. That could be worked around.

Comment: In the studio you tend to just get a control room mix & a headphone mix. The drummer might get his own, especially if there's a click-track, but I've never worked in any scenario where everybody demanded their own mix. Usually it's just a compromise that everybody can work with.

Comment: @Osh: Recording studios typically have mixers with tons of busses, so there is no problem providing individual musicians with their own headphone mix. Especially since you will use most of those busses during mixing, not recording, so they are sitting mostly unused anyway. Also, lots of studios have an Aviom system, where every musician can make their own mix independently of the recording engineer. Or, more recently, I have seen some high-profile studios with high-profile clients switch to Behringer P16 over the last couple of years.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Behringer has only one input, whatever gets put in will come out the same in all four outputs. All you can control is individual volume. The 800 would be a better bet, having enough outs, but a choice of two switchable inputs. So for a four piece band, two of those will fit the bill.

With 4 separate outs, a different mix could be sent to each of four. Or, since it's only a mixer, you could pan l and r and take two signals off the main out, I guess. Basically, you need a separate h'phone amp for each band member in order to facilitate personal mixes for each. If it was just for vox, then the same mix would surely do for all. That's what you end up with when going through the p.a. with no separate monitors (or simply one monitor mix).